# OS X Bootcamp - how to restore my existing Bootcamp partition?

Tags: macos, boot-camp

I recently reinstalled OS X. My Bootcamp partition is still there with Windows 7 on it - can I tell Bootcamp about this partition so I can continue to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling OS X shouldn't affect the windows 7 partition at all since once installed, the windows 7 partition no longer relies on bootcamp (all bootcamp does is put a lot of drivers and what not onto the partition). You should be able to boot up the bootcamp partition as usual.

Note: if you can't boot up windows 7 something went wrong, and that would require more details.

Comment: Cool! I thought I'd need to tell osx about it but as you said, the partition is still there, I just told osx to reboot into it :)

Comment: :) These little things are in my opinion what distinguishes os x from Windows! Just my opinion, though.